# What does this evaluation function mean?

Tags: predictive-models, validation, function

I am solving a prediction problem where I am supposed to predict the number of clicks, given some historical Data. I am told that my predictions will be evaluated by a normalized weighted mean square error which is:
[image: Error Function]

Can some one please explain the error function?

Thank you in advance.